# Turn Imported Netsuite CSV Files into Contact lists

Tags: crm, database-migration, netsuite, csv-import

I was wondering if it was possible to turn an imported CSV in Netsuite into a list of contacts, or leads/prospects that I could send emails to? Seems as of now, it is just an excel file in Netsuite. Is there a way I could turn that excel file into a contact group?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the import tool under setup > Import/Export > Import CSV records? It's on the help docs.

Just mark the contacts with somehting on the comments or a custom field and then make a dynamic group with a search pointing to that reference.